# Why is my Java copy constructor not returning the populated values of the new object?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to create another `koetinLList` object by making a copy of an existing `koetinLList` object. These are objects of a linked list.

```java
public  koetinLList(koetinLList aList) {
    koetinLList list = new koetinLList();
    if (aList.head != null) {
        list.head = new koetinNode(aList.head);
        koetinNode newListnode = list.head;
        koetinNode i = aList.head.next;
        while (i != null) {
            newListnode.next = new koetinNode(i);
            newListnode = newListnode.next;
            i = i.next;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

When I call this constructor as:

```java
koetinLList list = new koetinLList(lines);
```

My `koetinLList` list object appears to be constructed by my default constructor with values of null rather than initialized by the copy constructor.

Comment: In the constructor, a new `koetinLList` is created through the no-args constructor (`koetinLList list = new koetinLList();`). We should remove it and use `this` in its place instead. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic of constructors, e.g. [this one by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). --- Two remarks on the code: - class names should always start with an uppercase letter (`koetinLList` -> `KoetenLList`). - the `return;` is superfluous and can be removed.

Comment: You want to learn about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, anything else confuses your readers. And as Turing says, that local variable list that you are creating there ... it gets discarded after the constructor here exists. Long story short: the real answer is that you should step back and consult your book(s) how to correctly use constructors.

Comment: You've accidentally created *two* instances of koetinLList and have populated the wrong one (which then goes out of scope and is discarded).

Comment: @Turing85, Thank you, I forgot to remove `return;` when posting, it was just my way of inserting a break point to stop and examine what happened before exiting the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, a new `koetinLList` is created through the no-args constructor (`koetinLList list = new koetinLList();`). This instance is unreachable after the constructor call finishes, making it useless. Furthermore, we do not actually modify the `this` object in the constructor.

We should remove the object `koetinLList` from the constructor and use `this` in its place instead. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic of constructors, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

---

Two remarks on the code:

- class names should always start with an uppercase letter (koetinLList -> KoetenLList).
- the `return;` is superfluous and can be removed.